# How to set current CultureUI via XAML binding

Tags: wpf, xaml, textblock, currentculture

I have a TextBlock bound to a string. I want the string to be displayed in current UI culture of the application. I want to do this in XAML. The text block is simple like below.

`<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Text}"/>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `FrameworkElement.Language` property. The easiest way to do that for the whole application is to override the property metadata in the `App` class static constructor:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    static App()
    {
        FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(
            typeof(FrameworkElement),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag)));
    }
}
```

If you only want to set the culture for a specific control, you can bind its `Language` property to a property of your datacontext:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Something}" Language="{Binding TheLanguage}" />
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas, but, I need to do this for my custom control library. I happened to see the CultureConverter in binding. But, I dono't know how to use that to set the current culture. It is not a dependency property. :(